# how to avoid android vm release some singleton

Tags: android, singleton, android-memory

I've one android app which runs some tasks in background when user is not with app open.

The idea is the user opens the app and configure some tasks to be done in background then it goes using other apps and the tasks are being done.

in order to execute the tasks in background i created a `Service` so android keep it active even when the app is not on screen anymore...

In my app I've a facade which is responsible for the API requests to my server (this facade is a singleton). In order to create the singleton instance i need user interaction so he can provides the authentication info and sometimes confirm the login with 2factor auth.

the problem is that sometimes when the app is not foreground, android destroys the whole instance of the app (including the singleton) the background service keeps working because it is a service, but when the user re-launch the app and any activity tries to access the singleton it gets nullpointerexcetion

my singleton is way to complex to make parceable, which patter or design strategy should i follow to avoid this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should save the state of the singleton when the method `onSaveInstanceState` is called setting up a Bundle. Then, when the Activity is recreated again, `OnCreate` will be called and the framework will pass as parameter the Bundle that will also contain the data that you saved before. With that, you can set your singleton properties again. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Comment: as I said my singleton is to complex to implement parceable, and i would need to guess which activity is on when `onSaveInstanceState ` is called or even replicate the code to all activities... this is not a reasonable design pattern no api for android that uses singleton relly on developper to save its state on every single activity